# Probable prime test maximum probability error

Tags: probability, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, pseudoprimes

[1](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1jeraR7upR-IWIL-M2FfE-2epEDwxIbfy/view?usp=sharing) Suppose we have the following probable prime test for an integer $n$:

---

---

Choose any integers $a$ and $b$ such that

Jacobi$(a,n)=-1$ and $\gcd(b,n)=1$

[2] If $(x+b)^n = -x+b \mod (n,x^2-a)$, then $n$ is a probable prime, otherwise, $n$ is composite.

---

---

If $n$ is composite, the congruence cannot hold for too many $b$'s:

From a field theory perspective, $x+b$ is an element in the field $F(n^2)[x]/[x^2-a]$ which has order $n^2-1$ when $n$ is prime. It can be seen that

[3] $(x+b)^{n^2-1} = 1 \mod (n,x^2-a)$

from which we have analogues of Carmichael numbers (order 2 Carmichael numbers precisely).

So $(x+b)^n = -x+b \mod (n,x^2-a)$ implies that $(x+b)^{n^2-1} = 1 \mod (n,x^2-a)$, but the converse is not true:

$(x+3)^{2047^2-1} = 1 \mod (2047,x^2+1)$

$(x+3)^{2047} ≠ -x+3 \mod (2047,x^2+1)$

In a nutshell, this proves that there are no analogues of Carmichael numbers for this test. It also shows that the set of binomials for which [2] is true is a proper subset of the binomials for which [3] is true. Therefore I ask:

- What is the maximum probability of error if the test is done $k$ different times using different $x+b$ binomials? 
  In other words, for any composite number $n$, what are the maximum number of binomials $x+b$ that $n$ will pass the test (for any $a$ with Jacobi$(a,n)=-1$)?

(This question is analogous to how the Miller-Rabin declares a composite number prime with probability no more than $1/4^k$ for $k$ different rounds of the test)

I have also generated a list of ["pseudoprimes"](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1jeraR7upR-IWIL-M2FfE-2epEDwxIbfy/view?usp=sharing) to this test.